# can we use CoreData to manage offline data when we use SqlCipher to store data in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, sqlcipher

can we use CoreData to manage offline data when we use SqlCipher to store data in iOS or we should directly use Sql queries to manage data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear that there is any supported way to use SqlCipher and SQLite backed CoreData together.

It should be noted though, that current iOS devices have all of their flash storage encrypted by default.  This would provide security from offline attacks and adding a PIN to your iOS device would protect against live attacks.  Is there some specific reason you need to use SqlCipher that is not covered by whole-disk encryption?

Comment: Can you explain what really the flash encryption does? And can data be protected when the phone is jail broken and hackers try to fetch data ?

Comment: Please look at this http://www.medical-iphone-apps.com/blog/1300/demonstration-forensic-recovery-of-an-iphone-3gs/

Comment: The hardware encryption is great, but difficult to "trust", and sometimes it's not convenient to keep your device completely locked up, and you'd prefer to have, say passwords and secure credentials, in their own encrypted store, always protected from snoops and serious spooks.